# Comparing Two Splunk Events To See Which One Is Larger

Tags: events, splunk

I'm using a transaction to see how long a device is RFM mode and the duration field increases with each table row. How I think it should work is that while the field is 'yes' it would calculate the duration that all events equal 'yes', but I have a lot of superfluous data that shouldn't be there IMO.
I only want to keep the largest duration event so I want to compare the current events duration to the next events duration and if its smaller than the current event, keep the current event.

```
index=crowdstrike sourcetype=crowdstrike:device:json 
| transaction falcon_device.hostname startswith="falcon_device.reduced_functionality_mode=yes" endswith="falcon_device.reduced_functionality_mode=no"
| table  _time duration
```

| _time | duration |
| --- | --- |
| 2022-10-28 06:07:45 | 888198 |
| 2022-10-28 05:33:44 | 892400 |
| 2022-10-28 04:57:44 | 896360 |
| 2022-08-22 18:25:53 | 3862 |
| 2022-08-22 18:01:53 | 7703 |
| 2022-08-22 17:35:53 | 11543 |

In the data above the duration goes from 896360 to 3862, and can happen on any date, and the duration runs in cycles like that where it increases until it starts over. So in the comparison I would keep the event at the 10-28 inflection point and so on at all other inflection points throughout the dataset.
How would I construct that multi event comparison?

Comment: share some sample data - as @RichG noted, there's probably a much better way to accomplish your goal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your answers but it wasn't working out. I ended up talking to some professional splunkers and got the below as a solution.

````
index=crowdstrike sourcetype=crowdstrike:device:json  
| addinfo ```adds info_max_time```
| fields + _time, falcon_device.reduced_functionality_mode falcon_device.hostname info_max_time
| rename falcon_device.reduced_functionality_mode AS mode, falcon_device.hostname AS Hostname
| sort 0 + Hostname, -_time ``` events are not always returned in descending order per hostname, which would break streamstats```
 
| streamstats current=f last(mode) as new_mode last(_time) as time_change by Hostname ```compute potential time of state change```
| eval new_mode=coalesce(new_mode,mode."+++"), time_change=coalesce(time_change,info_max_time) ```take care of boundaries of search```
| table _time, Hostname, mode, new_mode, time_change
| where mode!=new_mode ```keep only state change events```
| streamstats current=f last(time_change) AS change_end by Hostname  ```add start time of the next state as change_end time for the current state```
| fieldformat time_change=strftime(time_change, "%Y-%m-%d %T")
| fieldformat change_end=strftime(change_end, "%Y-%m-%d %T")
``` uncomment the following to sort by duration```
```| search change_end=* AND new_mode="yes"
| eval duration = round( (change_end-time_change)/(3600),1)
| table time_change, Hostname, new_mode, duration
| sort -duration```
````

Answer (score 0):

By definition, the `transaction` command bundles together all events with the same hostname value, starting with the first "yes" and ending with the first "no".  There is no option to include events by size, but there are options that govern the maximum time span of a transaction (`maxspan`), how many events can be in a transaction (`maxevents`), and how long the time between events can be (`maxpause`).  That the duration value you want to keep (896360) is 10 days even though the previous transaction was only 36 minutes before it makes me wonder about the logic being used in this query.  Consider using some of the options available to better define a "transaction".

What problem are you trying to solve with this query?  It's possible there's another solution that doesn't use `transaction` (which is very non-performant).

Comment: I'm trying to see how long a device is in reduced functionality mode.
So I want to bundle all events where 'falcon_device.reduced_functionality_mode=yes' that are bound by 'falcon_device.reduced_functionality_mode=no' on either side and calculate the time between the first event and last event of the bundle. I also want all the bundles, so if it goes into RFM multiple times I have all those timespans.

Answer (score 0):

*Sans* sample data, something like the following will *probably* work:

```
index=crowdstrike sourcetype=crowdstrike:device:json falcon_device.hostname=* falcon_device.reduced_functionality_mode=yes
| stats max(_time) as yestime by falcon_device.hostname
| append
    [| search index=crowdstrike sourcetype=crowdstrike:device:json falcon_device.hostname=* falcon_device.reduced_functionality_mode=no
    | stats max(_time) as notime by falcon_device.hostname ]
| stats values(*) as * by falcon_device.hostname
| eval elapsed_seconds=yestime-notime
```